# Converting varchar in hh:mm:ss.nnnn format to actual time format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, type-conversion, data-conversion

I am relatively new to SQL and have come across a conversion issue that I am just not able to crack.

I currently have a table with the following `varchar` column:

| Logged_Off_Duration |
| --- |
| 8:59:41.000 |
| 7:16:05.000 |
| 7:02:22.000 |
| 9:13:32.000 |
| 0 |
| 14:22:56.000 |
| 10:39:00.000 |
| 7:37:59.000 |
| 6:57:57.000 |

I need to convert these values into time format (hh:mm:ss), but as shown in the above tables, I've got rows where the hours go past 9 (24 hour format) as well as rows where I simply have a 0 (zero). Is anyone able to assist me with converting this? I've tried a few simple cast and convert statements, but I keep on running into this issue:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Ideally fix your design; don't use a `varchar` to store data and time values. According to your data, for example, the "time" `'6:57:57.000'` is **after** `'14:22:56.000'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `try_convert()`:

```
select try_convert(time, Logged_Off_Duration)
```

The values that cannot be converted (e.g. `0`) are returns as `NULL` values.